# Correct path for custom CSS in Bootstrap

Tags: css, bootstrap-4

I have a Flask file with Bootstrap that I'm working on, and I'd like to apply custom CSS. My files are seeing each other for some reason, and I'm hoping someone can help me understand why. My structure is:

app (top folder)

-- templates (folder)

---- index.html (file in templates folder)

-- css(folder)

----bootstrap.min.css (file in css folder)

In my index.html file, I've tried:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/bootstrap.min.css">

<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
```

None of those have worked, though. Any ideas on how to link them properly?

Comment: The one starting with ../css/ should work. Are you using <base href...> by any chance?

Answer (score 0):

Try putting both files in the same directory, then add

`<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="bootstrap.min.css">`

If this is still not working, then there's something wrong on your code.

Answer (score 0):

File paths are used when linking to external files like:(in same folder)

> ```
> Web pages
> Images
> Style sheets
> JavaScripts
> ```

It is best practice to use `relative` file paths (if possible).

When using relative file paths, your web pages will not be bound to your current base URL. All links will work on your own computer (localhost) as well as on your current public domain and your future public domains.

So set you path like this then you use same file path for every file